# Keep Oracle.DataAccess.dll out of bin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, msbuild

I have a number of C# projects I maintain with Visual Studio (2013). Depending on the project, when I build I get an `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in my output folder. Why do my projects do this and how can I stop it?

No, none of my projects include `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in its references. In fact, my projects use only Sybase databases.

My company has a library dll—we'll call it `Company.dll`—that may be using the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, and my projects frequently use `Company.dll`. When I use `Company.dll`, `CopyLocal` is set to **False**, so `Company.dll` isn't copied to the output folder. (Our servers have `Company.dll` in the GAC.) The people maintaining `Company.dll` have stated that we should not be including `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in our builds.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the Post-build event of the project.

```
del $(TargetDir)Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

Comment: I've already implemented this. I was hoping to fix the source of the problem.

Comment: ok, thought I'd mention it in case you didn't know about it. I'll be watching this question for a better solution as well.